# Different terminology for spectrum?

Tags: functional-analysis, terminology, spectral-theory

The common terminology we get used to on spectrum of linear operators is

- point spectrum $ \sigma_p $,
- continuous spectrum $ \sigma_c $,
- residual spectrum $ \sigma_r $ .

However, we recently notice an terminology of another type:

- purely point spectrum $ \sigma_{pp} $ ,
- absolutely continuous spectrum $ \sigma_{ac} $ ,
- singularly continuous spectrum $ \sigma_{sc} $ .

The latter type is defined with respect to decomposition measure and orthogonal decomposition of spectral projections. For details, see for instance Chapter 3.3 in

> "G. Teschl: Mathematical Methods in Quantum Mechanics - With
>   Applications to Schrödinger Operators (2014)".

**Question:** What is the relation between above two terminologies, can we give an exact correspondence for them?

**Edit:** The relation I have found so far is $ \sigma_{pp} = \overline{\sigma_{p}} $.

One possibly useful result: Chapter IV, Proposition 1.16 in

> [Engel, Nagel: One-Parameter Semigroups for Linear Evolution Equations
>   (2000)]

However, I can not see clearly how to use this result to explain the connections between the two terminologies.

Comment: Is there a difficulty in directly comparing the definitions? Perhaps you can say more about some concrete thoughts you had about this. I ask so that I don't need to go hunting for that book to look up the definitions :)

Comment: @s.harp The latter definition depends mainly on decomposition of measure and orthogonal decomposition of spectral projections. However, I am not familiar with this part of knowledge.  You can go  Library Genesis for open access to this book.

Comment: @s.harp I have added some information which may be useful.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to read up the definitions in the book you described ([link](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/%7Egerald/ftp/book-schroe/schroe.pdf)). The two kinds of spectra really encode different things, and I do not believe they should be compared.

The first remark I would make is that the spectra of the "second kind" only make sense for self-adjoint (or normal) operators, that is operators where you have a spectral measure, whereas the spectra of the "first kind" can always be defined. Note however that if $A$ is self-adjoint that then $\sigma_r(A)=\emptyset$ always. That is for spectra of the "first kind" we only have access to $\sigma_p$ and $\sigma_c$ when we want to compare with $\sigma_{pp},\sigma_{ac},\sigma_{sc}$.

The second remark is that by definition $\sigma_p, \sigma_{c},\sigma_r$ are always disjoint, while $\sigma_{pp},\sigma_{ac},\sigma_{sc}$ may all overlap, indeed situations are possible where $\sigma_{pp}(A)=\sigma_{ac}(A)=\sigma_{sc}(A)$ (although not in separable Hilbert spaces, excepting the $0$ Hilbert space).

With these out of the way there are some things that can be said:

1. $\overline{\sigma_p(A)} =\sigma_{pp}(A)$.
2. If $H$ is separable and $A$ self-adjoint, then $\overline{\sigma_{c}(A)}\supseteq\sigma_{ac}(A)\cup \sigma_{sc}(A)$, although there are no restrictions on what can be in $\sigma_{ac}$ vs $\sigma_{sc}$ (both can be empty, or any one of the two can be empty, but I do not believe they can be the same in a seperable Hilbert space).
3. If $H$ is not separable you have no relation at all. For example $\sigma_c(A)$ can be empty but $\sigma_{ac}(A)$ and $\sigma_{sc}(A)$ can be anything.

If you are interested in these comments then I can describe how you can see them and the examples realising them in more detail. Lets describe a very singular example first:

> Let
> $$H=\ell^2([0,1])\oplus L^2([0,1],dx) \oplus \bigoplus_{\alpha\in [0,1]}L^2([0,1], d\mu_\alpha)$$
> where $\ell^2([0,1])$ is the space of functions $f:[0,1]\to\Bbb C$ so that $\sum_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)|^2<\infty$ (this is a **very big space**), $L^2([0,1],dx)$ is the usual $L^2$ space and $L^2([0,1],d\mu_\alpha)$ the $L^2$ of a singular measure $d\mu_\alpha$ on $[0,1]$ for which $\alpha$ is in the support. Now define the bounded self-adjoint operator $M_x:H\to H$, given by the formula $M_x(f) = ( x\mapsto x\cdot f(x))$ (note that this formula makes sense for each summand of $H$).
>
> You can check that $\sigma_p(M_x)=[0,1]=\sigma(M_x)$ and $\sigma_c(M_x)=\sigma_r(M_x)=\emptyset$, but also $\sigma_{pp}(M_x)=\sigma_{ac}(M_x)=\sigma_{sc}(M_x)=[0,1]$. If you remove any of the summands in the Hilbert space, you will make the corresponding $\sigma_{pp}$, $\sigma_{ac}$, $\sigma_{sc}$ empty.

Comment: @ s.harp Tnank you for comments. Are there any results that separate $ \overline{\sigma_c(A)} $ from $ \sigma_p(A) $ in the case that $ A $ self-adjoint on separable Hilbert space?

Comment: Correction: Thank you for answer.

Comment: You can have that $\sigma_p(A)$ and $\sigma_c(A)$ are both dense in $\sigma(A)$, you can also have either one of the two is empty. Now the main relation is that $\sigma_c(A)=\sigma(A)-\sigma_p(A)$ (and $\sigma(A)$ is closed, $-$ the set difference), hence if you want $\overline{\sigma_c(A)}$ and $\overline{\sigma_p(A)}$ to be disjoint you need $\sigma_p(A)$ and $\sigma_c(A)$ to both be closed. This condition alone is not enough, but I think it is the most basic necessary condition, and it is a bit of a restriction since $\sigma_p(A)$ is at most countable if $H$ is separable.

Comment: @ s. harp Clear explanation. But I am not familiar with the result "$ \sigma_p(A) $ is at most countable...". Where can i find it? Besides, if there exist some cases that we can locate $ \sigma_{ac} (A) $ in $ \sigma_{c} (A) $ for $ A $ unbounded self-adjoint on separable Hilbert space?

Comment: $\sigma_p(A)$ gives the eigenvalues of $A$, if $A$ is symmetric then any two eigenvectors of a different eigenvalue must be orthogonal. If $H$ is separable, then there can at most be a countably infinite system of mutually orthogonal vectors, and as such at most countably many eigenvalues of $A$. As to your second question, the unbounded multiplcation operator $M_x$ on $L^2(\Bbb R, dx)$ has $\sigma(A)=\sigma_c(A)=\sigma_{ac}(A)$ and all other spectra empty. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) In general the decomposition $H=H_{pp}\oplus H_{ac}\oplus H_{sc}$ will provided you with an isomorphism $L^2(\sigma(A), d\delta) \oplus L^2(\sigma(A), \widetilde{dx})\oplus L^2(\sigma(A), d\mu)$ on which the operator $A$ acts as the multiplication operator $M_x$. Here $d\delta$ is supported in $\sigma_{pp}(A)$ and has _only atoms_, $\widetilde{dx}$ is supported in $\sigma_{ac}(A)$ and is absolutely continuous wrt Lebesgue measure, and $d\mu$ is supported in $\sigma_{sc}(A)$ and is singular (without atoms) wrt the Lebesgue measure. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) (I believe that statement is exactly true in the case that $H$ is separable, in the non-separable case you will have that $H_{xx}$ is a (possibly big) sum of the corresponding type of $L^2$ spaces). I think this decomposition tells you very much about what these spectra mean. You should always think about $\sigma_{ac}(A)$ as values where $A$ acts as $M_x$ on something like $L^2([0,1],dx)$, $\sigma_{pp}(A)$ as eigenvalues of $A$ and $\sigma_{sc}(A)$ where $A$ acts as $M_x$ on an $L^2$ with a singular measure.

Comment: @ Actually I am expecting some cases in Schrodinger operators for the second question because i want to learn some ill-posedness result in them. I would like to see that some restrictions on potential functions yields that $ \sigma_{ac} (-\Delta + V) \subseteq \sigma_{c}(-\Delta + V) $.

Comment: Correction: @s. harp

Comment: Unfortunately I know next to nothing about Schrödinger operators, the only thing I know is that for a large class of useful potentials the spectrum is purely point. I would suggest asking another question specifically about this, as there a few knowledgeable people watching these tags.

Comment: @s. harp It is really nice of you to help me solve much confuse. Thank you and I would open a new question on the Schrodinger operators.